# Casting NSDictionary as Dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, casting, subscript

I've seen this solved in other questions - but I think that because this NSDictionary is accessed via subscript it's throwing some errors.

```
func pickRandomRecipe(arrayOfRecipes: NSArray) -> Dictionary<String,Any> {
let randomRecipeIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfRecipes.count)))

//Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fbfc4ce0208) to 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, protocol<>>' (0x7fbfc4e44358)
let randomRecipe: Dictionary = arrayOfRecipes[randomRecipeIndex] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
return randomRecipe
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case `NSDictionary` can only be casted to `[String: NSObject]`. If you want it to be of type `[String : Any]` you have to make a separate Dictionary:

```
var dict = [String : Any]()
for (key, value) in randomRecipe {
    dict[key] = value
}
```

Comment: This works but I had to use: **dict[key as! String] = value** because the original NSDictionaryI was casting from was: **let notificationDict = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary?**

Answer (score 4):

NSDictionary should be bridged to `[NSCopying: AnyObject]` or in your case `[String: AnyObject]`, rather than using `Any` (since that's a Swift-only construct).

But I would recommend **not using** NSDictionary at all. You could define your function as

```
typealias Recipe = [String: AnyObject] // or some other Recipe class

func pickRandomRecipe(recipes: [Recipe]) -> Recipe? {
    if recipes.isEmpty { return nil }
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(recipes.count)))
    return recipes[index]
}
```

Or perhaps even better:

```
extension Array {
    func randomChoice() -> Element? {
        if isEmpty { return nil }
        return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))]
    }
}

if let recipe = recipes.randomChoice() {
    // ...
}
```