# How do I convert NSDictionary to Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have already updated to XCode 8 and now I need to convert my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

Before, when I want to convert `NSDictionary` to `Dictionary`, I just wrote the following:

```swift
let post_paramsValue = post_params as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>
```

where `post_params` is `NSDictionary`.

But now with Swift 3, I am receiving this error:

```
NSDictionary is not convertible to Dictionary
```

Why? What's changed?

---

#### Edit 1

I've also tried the following:

```
let post_paramsValue = post_params as Dictionary<String,Any>
```

But that gives this error:

[image: 'NSDictionary!' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<String, Any>'; did you mean to use <code>as!</code> to force downcast?]

---

#### Edit 2

I've also tried the following:

```
let post_paramsValue =  post_params as Dictionary<String,Any>
```

Where I declare `NSDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary!`, but it doesn't work; I got this error:

[image: 'NSDictionary' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<String, Any>'; did you mean to use <code>as!</code> to force downcast?]

---

#### Edit 3

I've also tried the following:

```
let post_paramsValue =  post_params as Dictionary<String,Any>!
```

But I received this error:

[image: 'NSDictionary!' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<String, Any>!'; did you mean to use <code>as!</code> to force downcast?]

Comment: tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765875/casting-nsdictionary-as-dictionary-swift

Comment: @UmairAfzal thank you for your comment, but why i need to go through dictionary using loop , this is not convenient  , why apple need to make things harder ?

Comment: Well I do not know why, did you tried ? it works or not ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal i didn't try it ,i am pretty sure that it will work but this is not convenient . i need to do it with the best way. thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- `NSDictionary` in Objective-C has always non-optional values.
- `AnyObject` has become `Any` in Swift 3.
- Considering the first two "rules" `NSDictionary` can be bridge cast to `Dictionary`

---

```
let post_paramsValue = post_params as Dictionary<String,Any>
```

If the source `NSDictionary` is an optional you might use `as Dictionary<String,Any>?` or `as? Dictionary<String,Any>` or `as! Dictionary<String,Any>` or `as Dictionary<String,Any>!` depending on the actual type of the `NSDictionary`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i've tried this before  and it didn't work , i've edit the question

Comment: Then use the forced cast operator `as!` since the source dictionary is optional.

Comment: thanks again, why i can't use this :          let post_paramsValue = post_params as Dictionary<String,Any>!

Comment: You can use that, too

Comment: no it shows error message, one minute i will add the screen shot to my answer

Comment: Consider to declare the `NSDictionary` as non-optional.

Comment: it also doesn't work , i will add two screen shots one minute please

Comment: i've edited my question with all your suggestions , please have a look & let me what do you think, thanks

Comment: Have you tried the suggested `as!` (with exclamation mark)? I'd avoid to use `NSDictionary` in Swift at all unless you have no choice.

Comment: i did this "let post_paramsValue =  post_params as? Dictionary<String,Any> " just to avoid run time exception and it works. but why the other bridge suggestion doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

For those who have a problem with `NSDictionary`, simply use this extension:

#### Swift 3.0

```
extension NSDictionary {
    var swiftDictionary: Dictionary<String, Any> {
        var swiftDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()

        for key : Any in self.allKeys {
            let stringKey = key as! String
            if let keyValue = self.value(forKey: stringKey){
                swiftDictionary[stringKey] = keyValue
            }
        }

        return swiftDictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare the NSDictionary properly in objc

For example: `NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString*>` gets translated automatically to `[String: String]` in swift interfaces